# Putting an e-mail domain to blacklist

Tags: email, email-server

Is it possible for us to put a specific e-mail domain to blacklist?

I know you can personally tag and report as spam/scam e-mail for the incoming ones (to a specific email address, more like filtering them out), but I was wondering if you can put a specific e-mail domain to a blacklist so that domain gets filtered out in the spam folder automatically.

I am asking this because I own a small start-up company and I've been getting issues with our customers getting scammed by a specific e-mail domain.

How are the e-mails that we get from our daily spam folders get filtered out to spam folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you have control over the mail server, this should be possible with any server software. As you don't give any details on your email system, it's impossible to answer *how*.

Comment: Which mail server/service you use?

Answer (score 0):

What program do you use?
If postfix you can do it like create a sender_access file in /etc/postfix
you can add lines to this files like:

```
sales@domain.hu REJECT
@domain.hu REJECT
```

Save the file, run "`postmap  /etc/postfix/sender_access`"

edit the main.cf, at line check_client_access add hash:/etc/postfix/access

reload postfix

test it